# Large n approximation of double factorial

Tags: approximation, factorial

A text I am reading claims that

$$(-g)^{n} \frac{(4 n-1) ! !}{n !} \stackrel{n \gg 1}{\sim}\left(-\frac{g n}{e}\right)^{n}$$

I know the stirling approximation $n!\stackrel{n \gg 1}{\sim} n^n e^{-n}$. But how do I go about approximating the double factorial in the numerator?

Comment: Couldn't you just rewrite the double factorial with regular factorials and apply Stirling on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\pars{-g}^{n}\,{\pars{4n - 1}!! \over n!}} =
{\pars{-g}^{n} \over n!}\,\prod_{k = 0}^{2n - 1}\pars{2k + 1} =
{\pars{-g}^{n} \over n!}\,2^{2n}\prod_{k = 0}^{2n - 1}\pars{k + {1 \over 2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\pars{-g}^{n} \over n!}\,2^{2n}\,\pars{1 \over 2}^{\overline{2n}} =
{\pars{-g}^{n} \over n!}\,2^{2n}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/2 + 2n} \over \Gamma\pars{1/2}} =
{2^{2n}\,\pars{-g}^{n} \over \root{\pi}}\,{\pars{2n - 1/2}! \over n!}
\\[5mm] &\
\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{2^{2n}\,\pars{-g}^{n} \over \root{\pi}}\,
{\root{2\pi}\pars{2n - 1/2}^{2n}\expo{-2n + 1/2} \over \root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\,\,
\expo{-n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{2^{2n}\,\pars{-g}^{n} \over \root{\pi}}\,
{2^{2n}n^{2n}\,\, \bracks{1 - \pars{1/2}/\pars{2n}}^{\,2n}\expo{1/2} \over
n^{n + 1/2}}\,\expo{-n}
\\[5mm] &\ \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{2^{4n}\,\pars{-g}^{n} \over \root{\pi}}\,
n^{n - 1/2}\,\expo{-n} =
\bbx{{1 \over \root{\pi}}\pars{-16gn \over \expo{}}^{n}\,{1 \over n^{1/2}}}
\\ &
\end{align}

Comment: Could you please explain how do you get $\prod _{k=0}^{2 n-1} \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$?

Comment: @user824530 That's is the [rising factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Properties) $\displaystyle x^{\left(n\right)} = {\Gamma\left(x + n\right) \over \Gamma\left(x\right)}$.